# issue with .htaccess url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite url. Below is my code in .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^home?$  index.php 
RewriteRule  ^contact?$  contact.php 
RewriteRule  ^about?$  about.php 
RewriteRule  ^logout?$  logout.php   
RewriteRule  ^products?$  products.php 

RewriteRule  ^single-products/([0-9]+)$  single-products.php?product=$1
```

The pages without parameters works fine. But when I click on the page 'single-products' with parameters it displays like

```
single-products/1
```

and images and css styles not worked. When I changed the path css/syle.css to ../css/style.css it works.
Another problem is I can't return to another pages. When I coming to single-products, and click another menu option, url will displays like,

```
single-products/about
```

and displays page not found error. I requires /about. My menu link should be

```
<a href="single-products/1>Product 1</a>
```

How can I solve these issues. I searched many sites for a solution and didn't find one. Anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not sure  i fully understand the issue, do you also have a folder with the same name. it sounds like an issue with  the relative path you are using, try using the file path from the root folder starting with /, so for your css example you could use: /css/style.css

Comment: I don't have folder with the same name. When I go for another menu option, the path should be taken wrong.

Comment: try changed the relative paths to start with a /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For folders to ignore such as CSS etc. try this before your last rewrite rule:

```
# Directories to ignore
RewriteRule ^(css|images|js)(/.*)?$ - [L]
```

You might also want to consider using this too, if you plan of having a robots file etc.:

```
# Ignore favicon & robots.txt
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico - [L]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt - [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml - [L]
```

You are missing a closing quote:

```
<a href="single-products/1">Product 1</a>
```

As for your other question it's hard to answer as you haven't said how you want it to work..

```
single-products/1
```

is how the rewite rule is set to work.

Comment: My url looks like http://www.mysite.com/product when I click on products page. And http://www.mysite.com/single-products/1 , when I go for single products. Then if I click again on products, url will displays, http://www.mysite.com/single-products/product. I require http://www.mysite.com/product. How can I displays like that.

Comment: Well that's not a .htacess problem. As @Lupin says above, start your links with `/`. So: `<a href="/product">Product</a>` for example.